# Named pipe - run child process

Tags: c

I'm trying to use named pipe in C to run a child process in the background from a path in non-blocking mode and read the output of the child.

This is my code:

```
int fifo_in = open("fifo_1", O_RDONLY| O_NONBLOCK);
 int fifo_out = open("fifo_2", O_WRONLY| O_NONBLOCK);
 dup2(fifo_in, 0);
 dup2(fifo_out, 1);

 char app[] = "/usr/local/bin/probemB";
 char * const argsv[] = { app, "1", NULL };
 if (execv(app, argsv) < 0) {
            printf("execv error\n");

            exit(4);
 }
```

I will later use read function to read the child process output.

But the problem is that execv is blocking while it is reading the output from the process instead of allowing me to read.

Can someone help me to correct the above problem please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong in that [`execv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) is blocking.

If [`execv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) works, it will *never* return. It *replaces* your program. You need to [`fork`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) a new process for [`execv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):

```
if (fork() == 0)
{
    // In child process, first setup the file descriptors
    dup2(fifo_out, STDOUT_FILENO);  // Writes to standard output will be written to the pipe
    close(fifo_out);  // These are not needed anymore
    close(fifo_in);

    // Run the program with execv...
}
else
{
    // Unless there was an error, this is in the parent process
    close(fifo_out);

    // TODO: Read from fifo_in, which will contain the standard output of the child process
}
```

---

Another thing, you seem have two different and unconnected named pipes. You should open only *one* pipe, for reading in the parent process, and for writing in the child process:

```
int fifo_in  = open("fifo_1", O_RDONLY| O_NONBLOCK);
int fifo_out = open("fifo_1", O_WRONLY| O_NONBLOCK);
```

But if you only want to communicate internally, you don't need named pipes. Instead use anonymous pipes as created by the [`pipe`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) function.

Comment: You are correct about using fork, but i did not know that fork is needed in named pipe. Beside that. After fork, execv output to console, but i did not fire the read function yet...? how come

Comment: @John Updated answer with file descriptor setup and which to use for what

Comment: @John Note that `read` will not null-terminate your strings. Also remember to check what `read` *returns*.

Comment: execv still output the result to console, why?

Comment: @John Do the program you load write to standard error? Perhaps you should redirect that one too? Without knowing what it does, it's really impossible for us to tell.

Comment: yes, when i used unnamed pipe i got the output from read, but now read get nothing and execv output everything

Comment: @John Could it be the two-separate-and-unconnected-pipes issue that I added in my answer? And you *did* [create the pipe](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifo.html) before opening it? This is why it's so important to create a [mcve] to show us, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... but when the child process write and exit fast, execv then output to console everything and read become empty...

Comment: @John The `execv` function itself doesn't write to the console, only the program it runs can do that. And as long as we don't know what the program does we don't know what's really happening. And from [this `read` reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html): "If no process has the pipe open for writing, `read()` shall return `0` to indicate end-of-file." If the child process exist, there's no process keeping the pipe open for writing, and thus `read` returns `0`.

Comment: I understand that, but it weird that it happens :) anyway you have helped me really alot! thank you!

Comment: Just one last thing. Can you use setsid with named pipe or is that bad? the signal of parent is passed to child..

Comment: @John Unfortunately I'm not really experienced with `setsid` so I don't know.